# Подключение онлайн оплаты Opencart Израиль

Tags: opencart

Как Поставить онлайн оплату для сайта на
- Visa/MasterCard и PAYPAL (для оплаты не в Украине, а оплаты в Израиле, то есть этот сайт будут использовать в стране Израиль и там валюта ШЕКЕЛЬ то есть что бы люди могли рассчитыватся. Должны начислятся деньги на карту в валюте Израильской - это ШЕКЕЛЬ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** **МЕНЮ** > *Система* >> **Локализация**   >> **Валюта** добавляете новую валюту - ШЕКЕЛЬ. Настраиваете по шаблону валют из списка который там уже есть.
**МЕНЮ** > *Система* >>

**2.** **МЕНЮ** > *Система* >> **Настройки** >> **Локализация** меняете валюту по умолчанию на ШЕКЕЛЬ.